# Modeling a simple rule engine

Tags: scala, rule-engine

I am trying to model a school's Course and PreRequisites in Scala.

So to be able to take a course, you have to meet the pre-requisites which can be:

- courseA
- CourseA and CourseB and ..
- courseA or CourseB or ...
- ( courseA and courseB) or ( courseC and courseD)

So in short the prerequisite could be a course, or many courses and you can combine simple operators AND and OR.

So the basic idea is I want to model this in scala.

How could I model this in Scala?  I have never created a rule engine like this before, the actual rules will be stored in the database.

**I need some help outlining how to design the classes and understand how this would work, with performance in mind.**

The idea I had was I could loop through all the students and after loading the data in the rule engine I could then determine if a user has met the requirements of a course and can enroll in it.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern might inspire youto come up with an ISpecification trait etc...